# Using JSON data stored in a class?

Tags: python, json

I have a class with the following definition:

```
class Profile():
    def __init__(self, json_data):
        obj = json.loads(json_data)
        self.name = obj["name"]
        self.data = sorted(obj["data"])
```

The profile is in a separate file with this naming convention: `[profilename].json`

And as an example contains:

```
{"type": "profile", "data": [[0, 25], [90, 150], [180, 183], [211, 237], [234, 184], [313, 26]], "name": "leadfree"}
```

I need to be able to get the number from position `[4][0]` inside `data`, so the number `234` in this case, using a function inside the profile class.

I currently have:

```
def get_stage5time(self):
    return self.data[4][0]
```

But I am worried that isn't it, as it is using `sorted`, which may jeopardise the function. At the same time it may not have any effect, since anything in position `[0]` so `[0][0]`, `[1][0]` will actually at all times be in order, as time only goes up.

How would I be able to point to 234? Is the way I am doing it currently correct or am I missing something?

Comment: You know that data better than anyone else here. If the first value in that sublist always monotonically increases, then it's fine to do that. But what meaning does *"the time of the fourth value"* have?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. You can also pass a key to `sorted` to sort by a particular index. An unrelated comment, the method name looks very specific, would it not be better to have a single metgod that takes the positional index as an argument?